# Parsing a certificate string in go

Tags: go, x509

I'm using ssldump to extract the certificate in a communication. When i parse the result I obtain a string in go defined as:

```
var string certStr
certStr = "30 82 06 9f...."
```

How can I parse it to a X509 certificate?

**UPDATED**

I have tried to parse it directly:

```
certSlc := []byte(certStr)
cert,err := x509.ParseCertificates(certSlc)
```

But the result was:

```
Error:asn1: structure error: tags don't match (16 vs {class:0 tag:19 length:48 isCompound:true}) {optional:false explicit:false application:false defaultValue:<nil> tag:<nil> stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false}
```

Should I do another kind of conversion? maybe is the string incomplete or has got wrong type of cert?

Comment: Maybe have a look at this package : https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/
Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I have already seen that class but i'm getting a format error when I use ParseCertificates.
Maybe the problem is that I'm not able to generate the byte slice from the string correctly

Comment: Could you provide more details ? How are you converting your string byte slice ? Could you provide more code and show what you tried/failed to use ?

Comment: @MrReboot, You can directly convert a string to a bytes slice, there's not really an "incorrect" way to do it. Please show an example of the problem you're having, with a [mcve]

Comment: Does any of these examples help you? https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/example_test.go

Comment: I think my problem is parsing the hex string into the byte slice. This is what i need in go:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the error. The problem was in the source.
As I was explaining, my cert string was "30 82 06 09...". This source must be decoded with:

```
hex.DecodeString(certStr)
```

The problem is that hex decoding doesn't work with this format. The error I obtained was:

```
encoding/hex: invalid byte: U+0020 ' '
```

So, removing whitespaces and carriage returns in the original string is the solution to make it work.

After decoding in a byte slice the X509 certificate can be created with no problem.